# Logon issue with Windows 2016 server , Earlier I was able to login previously with code written in VB

Tags: vbscript, adsi

This code has worked previously:

```
dim objUser
On Error Resume next
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strAddress & "/" & strUserid & ", user")

objUser.SetPassword strPassword
objUser.SetInfo
```

Unfortunately, I am no longer able to login to Windows 2016 Server where earlier I was able to login. I'm not sure why this is happening. Can anyone help?

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`. It's hiding the information that might tell you how to fix this.